# How to make Java EE application go online without web hosting?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am learning to make a web application, and have a Java EE web application that uses Apache tomcat as server and web container. Currently, I am able to run the application and the tomcat server (localhost:8080/chatsystemWar)

I am trying to make the application go online without using web hosting. Could someone please help me understand the following?

1-Is it possible?

2-To my surprise, all computers at my house are able to access the application by replacing the "localhost" part with the computer name. How come?

3-Because of 2, I guess I have a working server and application, so all I should need is to somehow get the Internet to know about the application. Would buying a domain name help? What needs to be done after buying one?

4-Would modifying server.xml help?

Thank you very much. This is my first question on stack overflow, but I have been relying on you guys for at least a year now. You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, if you want to expose your web application to the wider internet, it must be hosted on an internet facing web server.

You could host it yourself, on your own machine, and open up port 80 on your router, and ask your ISP for a static IP address (or use a dynamic DNS service like [NoIP](http://www.noip.com/)), but that is not really ideal and exposes your machine to the internet for all and sundry to hack on.

A better choice is to purchase web hosting from a company that specializes in such things. Or you could spin up a web server on Amazon AWS and handle it yourself, but either way, you won't be opening up your home network to the internet.

This is a big topic and you'll have to do some more research to learn about all the different aspects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the security issues along with a direction to research on!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

Yes.

> To my surprise, all computers at my house are able to access the application by replacing the "localhost" part with the computer name. How come?

Because they are all on the same local network.

> Because of 2, I guess I have a working server and application, so all I should need is to somehow get the Internet to know about the application. Would buying a domain name help? What needs to be done after buying one?

Yes, a domain name would help, but is not needed. What you need is a static IP address (uncommon for homes, usually cost extra) and to configure your router/firewall to allow the traffic to flow.

Way too broad a topic to cover here.

> Would modifying server.xml help?

No.

Comment: The static IP part is what I needed. Thanks!